# Rstudio on macbook pro with retina display

Tags: macos, r, rstudio

I use Rstudio on my 15 inches macbook pro with retina display.

It seems that the plot window in the Rstudio doesn't support the high-DPI of the retina display, even after I zoom the plot.

This was fixed in a [recent update](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/release_notes_v0.96) regarding improving the text rendering (as seen [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/1280-rstudio-support-for-hidpi-mode-macbook-pro-retina-display)), though the plot images are still fuzzy in a similar manner.

Is there any way to change it and let it support the retina display? The plot is really ugly without supporting the retina display on my Mac.

Thank you!

Comment: eh...a little blurry...actually it's fine. but i just want to know if there is any way to fix it.

Comment: You're going to need to give some more details on what **exactly** is wrong with the image and what you would like fixed or this question is going to be pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: when retina macbook pro just came out, almost all the apps didn't support the retina display, right? the plot window of Rstudio is just like that.

Comment: I see this bug - http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/1280-rstudio-support-for-hidpi-mode-macbook-pro-retina-display - is this what you mean? If so, it looks like the RStudio guys have fixed this regarding text at least - http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/release_notes_v0.96

Comment: This update only fixed the font, not including the image in the plot window. I presume there will be some ways to let the image support the retina display just like the font. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: You can save you plot to a pdf. You should avoid a bunch of resolution problems that way.